# Using ASP.NET, Why here an error occurs: The server tag is not well formed

Tags: asp.net

```
<input type="text" class="inputField" id="searchName" value="XIA"/>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClientClick="window.location.replace('<%#ResolveUrl("~")%>/'+$('#searchName').val()); return false;" />
```

I want to redirect to a certain page based on the `~` directory and user input.

Answer (score 0):

It's this bit here.

```
OnClientClick="window.location.replace('<%#ResolveUrl("~")%>/'+$('#searchName').val()); return false;"
```

You've got double quotes and single quotes throughout the expression cause an early string termination.

You should make that a function and pass the data into it.